# What does the command "shutdown -t 100 +3 -h" mean?

Tags: shutdown

I have read the man page for `shutdown(8)` on a Fedora and OpenBSD system and I can't seem to find any documentation on the `-t` option. Is the `-t` a legacy option that is no longer supported in newer versions of the `shutdown(8)`?

Comment: What system are you using? You should consult the manual on the system where you plan to use the `shutdown` command. The command is non-standard, and the available options and their semantics may well be different on different systems (and even between releases of the same operating system).

Comment: I checked a few systems where the `shutdown` command is provided by systemd and upstart. Neither of them document a `-t` option. It would be useful to  [edit] the question to show where you came across this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://ss64.com/bash/shutdown.html:

```
   -t sec 
     Ensure a sec-second delay between killing processes
     and changing the runlevel.
```